# JsTree 3 Select a a particular node on load

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using the javascript library JsTree the current version to build a tree-kind structure in a web application. I would like to know how best to select a particular node within the tree once the tree is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ready.jstree event, than the jstree.select_node() method.

The ready event will occur when the tree is loaded, than you can select the node you want.

Answer (score 0):

Set the state property "selected=true" for the particular node to be selected on tree load.

```
$('#jstree_test').jstree({
    core: {
        data: [
            {
                id: 'parent1',
                parent: '#',
                text: 'p1',
                'state' : {
                     'opened' : true,
                     'selected' : true
                 }
            },
            {
                id: 'child1',
                parent: 'parent1',
                text: 'c1'
            },
            {
                id: 'child2',
                parent: 'parent1',
                text: 'c2'
            },
            {
                id: 'child3',
                parent: 'parent1',
                text: 'c3'
            }
    ]
}
});
```

JS Bin Demo [Link](http://jsbin.com/xapeq/1/)